# How to save data in localStorage that will stay there we close the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I wrote the following script and ran it in console:

```
var data = "dfsfds";
localStorage.getItem("data");
localStorage.setItem("data",data);
```

Then, I closed the broswer and reopened it. When I typed in console:

```
localStorage.getItem("data");
```

I got "undefined".

I think that Local Storage is supposed to stay in the browser memory after the browser is closed. Why doesn't it happen here?

Comment: You could use cookies as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must run this code from a page loaded from a domain. This means that the code must be running on a server that is accessed via HTTP. That's how the browser keeps one site's `localStorage` data separate from another.

The code below shows how to do this, but it won't work here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, due to sandboxing. You can see a working version **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/xt188soy/12/)**. Fill in your name, then click the button, copy the URL, close the browser and then open a new browser tab and return to the page.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  var g1 = document.querySelector(".greeting1");
  var g2 = document.querySelector(".greeting2");
 
  // Check localStorage to see if the user has already told us their name
  var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
  if(name){
    // Put the name into the <span>
    document.getElementById("user").textContent = name;
    
    // Hide the initial greeting and show the welcome back greeting
    g1.classList.add("hide");
    g2.classList.remove("hide");

  } else {
    // Show the initial greeting and hide the welcome back greeting
    g1.classList.remove("hide");
    g2.classList.add("hide");  
  }

  // Set up a click event handler for the button
  var btn = document.querySelector("button");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // When the button is clicked, save the value from the textbox into localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("name", document.querySelector("input").value);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="greetings">
  <div class="greeting1">
    <p>Please enter your name: <input type="text"><button>Save my name</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="greeting2 hide">
    <p>Welcome back <span id="user"></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not true that the "code must be running on a server that is accessed via HTTP."  Temp storage will work even when opening an HTML file from your local computer.

Comment: @Dale Only if you access that local file through a locally running server. `localStorage` will not work without a sever. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Exceptions

Comment: Please create a file with the following contents on your local drive and open it.  It will successfully store to local storage and retrieve.  After running once, remove the setItem call and it still works.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Dale I stand corrected. At the time that I posted this answer, `localStorage` was not supported unless you were working with the HTTP/HTTPS protocols.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Scott.  Would you like to edit the answer?  I would, but I'm not sure what the stackoverflow protocol/etiquette is here.

Comment: @Dale The answer shouldn’t be updated because it’s the right answer for when the question was asked. These comments will serve the purpose of providing updated information.